# CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config in dynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I have created an assumed role which has the access of `dynamoDB` of other account, and I am getting the assume role credential using `AWS` `STS`.

```
var sts = new AWS.STS({apiVersion: '2011-06-15', region:'us-east-1', endpoint: 'https://sts.amazonaws.com'});


console.log("Before calling the assume role");
sts.assumeRole({
    DurationSeconds: 3600,
    RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/crossAccount',
    RoleSessionName: 'awssdk'
}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        // an error occurred
        console.log('Cannot assume role');
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    } else {
        // successful response
        console.log('Role assumed');

        // Query function
        var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10', credentials: data, region: 'eu-west-1'});
        console.log("dynamo db   " + JSON.stringify(dynamodb));



        var params = {
            Key: {
            "Tid": {
            S: "123"
        },
        },
            TableName: "MYTable"
        };

        dynamodb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) { console.log(err, err.stack); console.log("failed"); }// an error occurred
            else  {   console.log(data);  console.log("success"); }         // successful response
        });
```

Following is the exact error :

```
{ CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config at credError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:317:40) at getStaticCredentials (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:338:15) at Config.getCredentials
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AWS.Credentials` is helping in resolving `getStaticCredentials`. Also, now you can use this credential for accessing other resources as well if you have permission for those resources. This also helps you to just use credentials only for those resources which you need to access from other `aws` account. You don't need to set credential globally.

```
var sts = new AWS.STS({apiVersion: '2011-06-15', region:'us-east-1', endpoint: 'https://sts.amazonaws.com'});


console.log("Before calling the assume role");
sts.assumeRole({
    DurationSeconds: 3600,
    RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/crossAccount',
    RoleSessionName: 'awssdk'
}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        // an error occurred
        console.log('Cannot assume role');
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    } else {
        // successful response
        console.log('Role assumed');

        // resolving static credential
        var creds = new AWS.Credentials({
          accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
          secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
          sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken
        });

        // Query function
        var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: configuration.API_VERSION, credentials:  creds, region: configuration.REGION});
        console.log("dynamo db   " + JSON.stringify(dynamodb));
        var params = {
            Key: {
              "Tid": {
                S: "123"
              },
            },
            TableName: "MYTable"
        };

        dynamodb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) { console.log(err, err.stack); console.log("failed"); }// an error occurred
            else  {   console.log(data);  console.log("success"); }         // successful response
        });
    }
```

Comment: This works! In my case; the issue was fixed by taking those `data.Credentials.*` fields from STS data then create an `AWS.Credentials` object to provide it in the `AWS.DynamoDB` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the client configuration as per the error. Try the following;

python

```
    # Create IAM client
    sts_default_provider_chain = boto3.client('sts')

    print('Default Provider Identity: : ' + sts_default_provider_chain.get_caller_identity()['Arn'])

    role_to_assume_arn='arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/roleName'
    role_session_name='test_session'

    response=sts_default_provider_chain.assume_role(
        RoleArn=role_to_assume_arn,
        RoleSessionName=role_session_name
    )

    creds=response['Credentials']

    sts_assumed_role = boto3.client('sts',
        aws_access_key_id=creds['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=creds['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=creds['SessionToken'],
    )

    print('AssumedRole Identity: ' + sts_assumed_role.get_caller_identity()['Arn'])
```

node

```
    const getSTS = async () => {
      const sts = new AWS.STS({ region: process.env.REGION });
      const params = {
        RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/someRole',
        RoleSessionName: 'CrossAccountCredentials',
        ExternalId: '1234567-1234-1234-1234-123456789012',
        DurationSeconds: 3600,
      };

      const assumeRoleStep1 = await sts.assumeRole(params).promise();
      console.log('Changed Credentials');

      const accessparams = {
        accessKeyId: assumeRoleStep1.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: assumeRoleStep1.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
        sessionToken: assumeRoleStep1.Credentials.SessionToken,
      };
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @MC_ for solution, but I didn't get problem getting credential. It was dynamoDB which is not able to resolve getStaticCredential credential if you see error log. Also I have solved this problem, i'll post code later today and also sorry I won't be able to test your code as of now.